# Zuul Proxy does NOT work on Tomcat vai SpringBootServlet

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, servlets, war, netflix-zuul

I'm seeking for a help with an issue I'm facing with Zuul which is not working on Tomcat being packaged into WAR.

Standalone it works perfectly well, but when I change packaging to war and deploy to Tomcat - requests does not seem to reach Zuul.

I have extended SpringBootServletInitializer and overridden configure() method, but that does not help.

**Note**: please do NOT advise me to run SpringBoot standalone with embedded Tomcat - that does not work as I need to incorporate an API gateway into existing infrastructure set up. In other words I need to implement a gateway given a boundary condition - it has to be deployed on Tomcat application server.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
public class GatewayApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

...

@override 
protected StringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
return application.sources(GatewayApplication.class);
}
}
```

> application.yml

```
zuul:
    routes:
        freebeer:
            path: "/beer/**"
            url: "https://freedom.com:443"
        default:
            path: "/**"
            url: "http://landing.com/"
```

It works perfectly fine when I'm running standalone app with embedded Tomcat e.g.:
 - request to http://localhost:8080/ is nicely redirected to http://landing.com/ 
 - as well as ..:8080/beer is nicely redirected to freedom.com

But in case of WAR deployed to Tomcat - nothing works:
 - request to http(s)://tomcat.intranet.com:12345 welcomes me with message that nothing is there and suggests to add web content
 - request to http(s)://tomcat.intranet.com:12345/beer gives me 404 with message that origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or that it's not willing to disclose that one exists

Looks like I'm missing something very obvious. But I've run out of patience to figure it out and calling for help :)

Comment: No ideas? May be I either need to rename war to ROOT.war or change URL in browser? :)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Requests were simply sent to wrong context - to app server root instead of web app specific. I solved it by naming war as ROOT.war